# How to be lazy effectively?

Tags: discussion

It's too much work to refer to our site each time with the formal name of **Unix and Linux Stack Exchange**, so we tend to shorten it. I have so far seen 4 ways of doing so:

- **unix.SE** - This seems to me more commonly-known but there is an existing site with that exact url; even if there wasn't, `.se` is a top-level domain.
- **unix.SX** - Gets rid of the existing site problem, but *.sx* still looks a top-level doman (we don't have them all memorised)
- **UL** - Ummm... too much little info (who would guess?), but at least it covers the **L** part of the site.
- **unix-SE** - Gets rid of the *is this a url* question, and we get to keep the more common `se` thing, instead of now having to get used to the `sx` thing.

You can easily guess which one I'd go with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SE is the usual abbreviation for Stack Exchange as a whole. “[SEI](http://www.google.com/search?q=SEI+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Achat.stackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Achat.stackexchange.com)” is the common abbreviation for Stack Exchange, Inc. (the company); nobody uses “[SXI](http://www.google.com/search?q=SXI+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Achat.stackoverflow.com+OR+site%3Achat.stackexchange.com)”.

[`.sx`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.sx) is likely to become a TLD soon, so it's not really better than `.se`.

I sometimes use U&L when the context makes an SE site name reasonably expected and I expect readers to be familiar with the existing sites (otherwise Unix needs to be spelled out, and sometimes even Linux).

Although domain names are case-insensitive, they are almost always written in lowercase, so I think “Unix.SE” or “unix.SE” are sufficiently unambiguous. Not that there's much of a risk of confusion with “unix.se” anyway.

Comment: is Sweden even a real country? I have my doubts. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73836/can-stackoverflow-inc-purchase-the-se-top-level-domain/81715#81715

Comment: @Jeff: Note how I refrained from suggesting the compromise of including both the E and the X.

Comment: I use Unix SE with a space... no . or - needed.

Comment: didn't that used to be an alt. newsgroup?